# pandas ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups

Tags: python, pandas

When using regular expression, I get:

```
import re
string = r'http://www.example.com/abc.html'
result = re.search('^.*com', string).group()
```

In pandas, I write:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['index', 'url'])
df.loc[len(df), :] = [1, 'http://www.example.com/abc.html']
df.loc[len(df), :] = [2, 'http://www.hello.com/def.html']
df.str.extract('^.*com')

ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups
```

How to solve the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html), you need to specify a *capture group* (i.e., parentheses) for `str.extract` to, well, extract.

> `Series.str.extract(pat, flags=0, expand=True)`
>   For each subject
>   string in the Series, extract groups from the first match of regular
>   expression pat.

Each capture group constitutes its own column in the output.

```
df.url.str.extract(r'(.*.com)')

                        0
0  http://www.example.com
1    http://www.hello.com
```

```
# If you need named capture groups,
df.url.str.extract(r'(?P<URL>.*.com)')

                      URL
0  http://www.example.com
1    http://www.hello.com
```

Or, if you need a Series,

```
df.url.str.extract(r'(.*.com)', expand=False)

0    http://www.example.com
1      http://www.hello.com
Name: url, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 14):

You need specify column `url` with `()` for match groups:

```
df['new'] = df['url'].str.extract(r'(^.*com)')
print (df)
  index                              url                     new
0     1  http://www.example.com/abc.html  http://www.example.com
1     2    http://www.hello.com/def.html    http://www.hello.com
```

Comment: In my case enclosing it in parentheses solved the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know if there's any way do get the capture group 0? Get the matched string without adding brackets?

Answer (score 5):

Try this python library, works well for this purpose:

Using [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html)

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
df['domain']=df.url.apply(lambda x:urlparse(x).netloc)
print(df)

  index                              url           domain
0     1  http://www.example.com/abc.html  www.example.com
1     2    http://www.hello.com/def.html    www.hello.com
```