# pulling mixed letters and numbers

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string, pandas, extract

```
import pandas as pd      
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['This 1A1619 person BL171111 the A-1-24',
                                      'dont Z112 but NOT 1-22-2001',
                                      'mix: 1A25629Q88 or A13B ok'], 
                              'IDs': ['A11','B22','C33'],
                              })
```

I have the dataframe above. I want to extract the all the mixed letters and number strings (`1A1619`,`BL171111`, `Z112`, `1A25629Q88`, `A13B`)  . To do so, I tried to combine code from [replace words and strings pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57661996/replace-words-and-strings-pandas) and  [identify letter/number combinations using regex and storing in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57650538/identify-letter-number-combinations-using-regex-and-storing-in-dictionary). My code looks like this

```
pat = r'(?<!\S)(?:[a-zA-Z]+\d|\d+[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]*(?!\S)'
dataframe['new'] = dataframe['Date'].str.extract(pat, expand=True)
```

But doing so gives me an error

```
ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups
```

I looked here [pandas ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54343378/pandas-valueerror-pattern-contains-no-capture-groups) but I am still unsure how to alter my code so I can extract all the mixed letters and number strings (`1A1619`,`BL171111`, `Z112`, `1A25629Q88`, `A13B`)

What can I do to my code

```
dataframe['new'] = dataframe['Date'].str.extract(pat, expand=True)
```

to extract what I want?

Comment: See if wrapping all of it with `()` works: `pat = r'((?<!\S)(?:[a-zA-Z]+\d|\d+[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]*(?!\S))'`. The `()`s create a capture group.

Comment: yes, that works!

Comment: such a simple fix...can you please explain why `()` creates the "capture group", and what a "capture group" is exactly?

Comment: In Pandas, `str.extract` *returns only the capturing group contents. The pattern used with extract requires at least 1 capturing group*. [*Capturing group*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) details.