# adding NaN where regex doesn't match

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string, pandas, nan

```
import pandas as pd
df= pd.DataFrame({'Date':['nothing ',
                              'This 1A1619 A124 person BL171111 the A-1-24 and ',
                              'dont Z112 but NOT 12-24-1981',
                               'nada here either',
                              'mix: 1A25629Q88 or A13B ok A1 the A16'],
                      'IDs': ['A11','B22','C33', 'D44', 'E55'],
                      })
```

This is a follow up and variation to [pulling mixed letters and numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57718728/pulling-mixed-letters-and-numbers). Using this code

```
pat = r'((?<!\S)(?:[a-zA-Z]+\d|\d+[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]*(?!\S))'
df['Date'].str.extractall(pat)
```

gives me

```
        0
   match    
1   0   1A1619
    1   A124
    2   BL171111
2   0   Z112
4   0   1A25629Q88
    1   A13B
    2   A1
    3   A16
```

I am looking to add `NaN` where the `regex` doesnt match. So I would like something this instead

```
        0
   match    
0   NaN
1   0   1A1619
1   A124
2   BL171111
2   0   Z112
3   NaN
4   0   1A25629Q88
    1   A13B
    2   A1
    3   A16
```

How would I alter my code to do so?

Comment: simple thing is loop through the list, check for individual element with regex if it matches add that to final list, if not just use NaN as default value

Comment: how about df['Date'].str.findall(pat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `s` is the return of `df['Date'].str.extractall(pat)`, we can:

```
i = df.index.difference(s.index.get_level_values(0))
o = pd.DataFrame({0: np.nan}, index=[i, [0]*len(i)])
adjust = lambda s,o: pd.concat([s, o]).sort_index()
```

Then

```
>>> adjust(s,o)
```

---

```
                  0
  match            
0 0             NaN
1 0          1A1619
  1            A124
  2        BL171111
2 0            Z112
3 0             NaN
4 0      1A25629Q88
  1            A13B
  2              A1
  3             A16
```